# Dragging visual blocks in tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg, tinymce-plugins

short question as I did not find a plugin and/or solution yet:

Is it somehow possible, to drag a visual block and drop it to another position? I am thinking of a way to allow content creators to easily rearrange blocks within the tinyMCE editor, whether they are paragraphs, divs etc.

All hints pointing closer to a solution (premium, open source, custom plugins etc.) are welcome! Thanks in advance.